# Problem with <pre> in markdown

Tags: bug, status-norepro, markdown, markdown-rendering, internet-explorer

Have a look at this question: [Can we add a creation_date to the /sites method?](https://stackapps.com/questions/1181/)

Now hit edit and look at the preview. Doesn't match, does it?

**Edit:** Yes, I am aware that I didn't close the `<pre>` tag.

## Repro attempt:

{
    "name": "Gaming Meta",
    "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/gamingmeta/logo.png",
    "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.gaming.stackexchange.com",
    "site_url": "http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com",
    "description": "Q&A about the Gaming site",
    "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchymeta/apple-touch-icon.png",
    "state": "linked_meta",
    **"creation_date": 1279825996,**
    "styling": {
        "link_color": "#3D3D3D",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#666666",
        "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
}

*Notice the `creation_date` item.*

On IE7 (and IE8's IE7 compatibility mode), this results in author/editor signatures wandering off the right side of the page:

[...where gouls devour them... http://shog9.com/so_meta_58145_bad_syntax.png](http://shog9.com/so_meta_58145_bad_syntax.png)

Comment: Considering closing the <pre> tag gets you the proper display, and that closing your tags is generally a good idea, wouldn't that be a good solution, as opposed to trying to get functionality for syntax you shouldn't be using?

Comment: @Grace: Well, because people forget and don't notice that they've forgot... like me.

Comment: @George - Invalid input will, in *most* situations, yield an undesired result. I have to agree that this *isn't* a bug, invalid HTML = unpredictable results.

Comment: I could consider this a bug if it did something *really bad*, like corrupt the layout of the page or allowing script injection. But messing up the formatting of the post itself seems about par for the course...

Comment: @Shog9: It does mess up the layout on IE7 (but not Opera).

Comment: @mmyers: ah, so it does. Poor IE7 users...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the point of this request? You didn't close the `<pre>` tag, so somehow that is our bug?

Are you aware that Markdown is not supported inside HTML blocks? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help specifically where it says

> Markdown can't be used within HTML blocks.

I tested on dev and unclosed `<pre>` is indeed stripped:

test input:

```
blah

<pre>
blah
```

output:

```
<p>blah</p> 

<p> 
blah</p>
```

Comment: Yes, I am just pointing out how the markdown system degrades when someone inadvertently forgets to close a tag - and doesn't notice it.

Comment: Maybe some sort of warning message between the edit box and the preview would help with this?